# To check a checkbox when user clicks on the text adjacent to it in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox

I have a array of labels which i used display looping over using ng-repeat. I have a checkbox implemented and a label(inside a span) adjacent to it. I want to check the adjacent checkbox when the user clicks on the corresponding span element.

```
<bv-checkbox ng-model="i.checked" ng-change="inputChanged()""></bv-checkbox>
<span ng-bind="i.displayName"></span>
```

I do not have an id in place hence i cant use label "for" property.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add an `ng-click` on the `span` element to do it?

```
<bv-checkbox ng-model="i.checked" ng-change="inputChanged()""></bv-checkbox>
<span ng-bind="i.displayName" ng-click="i.checked=true;"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..It might help you

```
<div ng-repeat="emp in employees">
<div class="action-checkbox">
<input id={{emp.name}} type=checkbox value="{{emp.name}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(emp.name)">
<label for={{emp.name}}></label>{{emp.name}}
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are many ways to make this happen without using `<label>`, but I think you should use it because it is the standard way of doing it.

To solve the no id issue, you can create an id dynamically by using other fields of the object (e.g. name or index) (mentioned in @Natarajan's answer)

You can also use a `<label>` to surround both elements if they are adjacent (not recommended).

```
<label>
  <bv-checkbox ng-model="i.checked" ng-change="inputChanged()""></bv-checkbox>
  <span ng-bind="i.displayName"></span>
<label>
```

Although this might create some styling issue that needs to be fixed in CSS.